# Swift 2.2 equivalent code for forControlEvents: .AllEvents ^ (.TouchDown)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ios9

The following code worked on swift 1.2 for a method to be invoked on all control events expect the mentioned one.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "myMethod:", forControlEvents: .AllEvents ^ (.TouchDown))
```

What I am trying now is:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myClass.myMethod(_:)), forControlEvents: .AllEvents ^ (.TouchDown))
```

What would be the swift 2.2 equivalent code for the same? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It has nothing to do with iOS 8 vs iOS 9. It has to do with the version of Xcode / Swift you're using.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. And what would the swift 2.2 equivalent code be?

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent is:

```
UIControlEvents.AllEvents.exclusiveOr(.TouchDown)
```